# nuxtjs content not found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an issue with nuxtJS content module. I can't find the problem. What's wrong with my code ? This is my folder structure.

[image]

Here is my `_slug.vue` code block

```
export default {
  async asyncData({ params, $content }) {
    console.log(params)
    return {
      content: await $content('shipping-service', params.slug).fetch(),
    }
  },
}
```

Once I click the route `/shipping-services/amazon` not found error returns.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are using this module https://content.nuxtjs.org/ ?

Comment: Sure, it defined under `modules` section like this, `'@nuxt/content',`

Comment: Please try to enrich this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-content-playground-l164h) in order to debug it

Comment: It's weird but once I change content extension `.json` to `.md` it's start working.

Comment: i think it's related to the config

Comment: Yes, I think so :)